# How do I randomly generate an element across a 5x10 grid of arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm working on a simple text-based game similar to pacman, where the letter 'c' serves as the character that the player controls using user-inputs. Across the 5x10 grid, 10 'coins' which are represented by 'o' should be randomly generated across the board. The grid, on the other hand, is composed of the symbol '-'.

The player icon, along with the coins should be randomly generated.

I've coded out a simple solution for a single line where I randomly pop an element out of a list and take that same index and insert a coin. Here's the code:

```
array=['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-',]
separator = ' '

def pop():
    pos = random.randint(0,9)
    return pos

array.pop(pop())
array.insert(pop(), 'o')
print (separator.join(array))
```

Now I just need to make it into a 5x10 grid. Problem is, I don't know how to randomly insert 11 elements (10 coins and the player icon) across 5 rows of arrays. Help!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using your custom pop() function twice:

```
array.pop(pop()) 
array.insert(pop(), 'o')
```

you can use:

```
index = pop()
array.pop(index)
array.insert(index, 'o')
```

or a better solution would be:

```
index = pop()
array[index] = 'o'
```

with `random.sample()`

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample

indexes = list(range(50))
chosen = sample(indexes, k=11)

grid = np.array(["-"] * 50)

grid[chosen[0]] = "c"
for i in range(10):
    grid[chosen[i+1]] = "o"

grid = grid.reshape((5, 10))
print(grid)
```

k=11 means 1 character (c) and 10 coins (o)

Comment: Thanks for answering!!! How might I be able to apply this across 5 arrays?

Comment: first thing comes to my mind is using random.sample which gives you a sample from your list and guarantees that all elements of the sample are different. I will edit my answer with the code.

Comment: works great thank you! although, I would want to index all of the individual coins and the character. this is because I want the player to be able to move the character and grab each individual coin. I am thinking of popping each individual coins but I do not know how to index every printed coin element.

Comment: indexes of the character and coins are in `chosen`. but if you want coordinates, you can use division and mod operations like shown in [Troy D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6410450/troy-d)'s answer

Answer (score 0):

So, first we'll generate a 2d array from a list of lists using a width of 5 and a height of 10:

```
import random

w, h = 5, 10
two_d_array = [['-' for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
```

Next, because you want to place these items randomly without choosing the same location twice, we want to generate a random sample that doesn't have repeat values:

```
samples = random.sample(range(w * h), 10)
```

Then, for each of these sample values, we'll take the integer value of the sample value divided by the width, and we'll get the column value by getting the remainder of the sample divided by the width.  And replace with the value you want.

```
for s in samples:
    row = int(s/w)
    column = s % w
    two_d_array[row][column] = 'o'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering! This worked great! Although it had the TypeError: expected str instance, list found at first when trying to print two_d_array, so I did this:

```for grid in two_d_array:
    print(separator.join(grid))
```